# How to fix future relative time in dayjs?

Tags: dayjs

I have a code like this:
`dayjs().to(post.date)`

and it prints: 'in 6 hours'.

How to convert date to my timezone in dayjs?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want. Guess you want to convert post.date timezone, you can do like `dayjs().to(dayjs(post.date).tz("America/Toronto",true))`

the document is on https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone